# Set PATH when launching a new terminal from a script in Mac

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal

I need to launch a new terminal window from a script and set an environment variable in this new terminal so I can run a few commands there.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:$1
open -a Terminal /my/path/
```

Notice `$1` is a value I'm sending when running the script, like this:

```
./myScript /my/env/variable/path
```

The terminal is opened but the env variable is not set. I have a similar script in Linux that works fine, but for some reason this line `PATH=$PATH:$1` is not working as expected in Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely (almost certainly) the rc scripts running in the new shell in your terminal are overriding that value. Test with an environment variable other than PATH -- say, `FOOBAR` (be sure to export it; you don't need to export PATH here since it's already in the environment, but FOOBAR won't be) -- and you'll likely see it in your terminal.

Comment: You should use `export` for set the variable

Comment: @Zulu, that's not mandatory for PATH, since it's already exported. Changes to variables already in the environment are propagated through automatically.

Comment: BTW -- `#bin/bash` is not `#!/bin/bash`. Details matter; a shebang that doesn't start with _precisely_ `#!` won't be honored.

Comment: `#!bin/bash` isn't `#!/bin/bash` either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATH` is a special case, because it's going to be overridden by almost any default set of dotfiles. You'll need to review your user's `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, etc.

However, if I run:

```
hello=world open -a Terminal .
```

...and in that terminal, run

```
echo "$hello"
```

...the environment variable is successfully propagated through.

---

Now, how can you fix this? One way is to modify the user's dotfiles to respect another variable you're passing through:

```
foo_path=$1 open -a Terminal .
```

...and, in `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc`, as appropriate:

```
[ -n "$foo_path" ] && PATH=$PATH:$foo_path
```

You could even replace PATH wholesale when an override value is available, passed through a different name:

```
# in the user's dotfiles
[ -n "$PATH_override" ] && PATH=$PATH_override

# in your script
PATH_override=$PATH:$1 open -a Terminal .
```

Note that putting the assignment on the same line as the command is an important detail -- doing that exports the variable into the environment for the scope of that single command, without needing to use an explicit `export` call.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, your terminal emulator opens a non-login shell by default, since at some point, your login session was started by a process whose environment was inherited ultimately from a login shell, which typically has initialized `PATH` to some starting value.

OS X, however, doesn't run its window manager from a login shell, so the Terminal application starts a login shell by default. The very first thing that happens in that process is that `/etc/profile` is sourced, which runs `/usr/libexec/path_helper` to produce a shell command to initialize `PATH`. That command, however, sets it to an absolute path, rather than appending anything to a previous value. As a result, the shell in the new terminal window overwrites any changes to `PATH` it might have inherited from your script.

Some possible options follow, but which one you choose depends heavily on how you are using your script and how you want to handle it.

- Configure Terminal to open a non-login shell instead of a login shell.
  However, this would prevent `/etc/profile` or your own `.bash_profile` from executing; you may want to look into starting Terminal with a profile
  other than the default from your script, although doing so will probably require something more complicated than a simple `open` command (likely involving AppleScript).
- Alter `PATH` in the script being opened in the Terminal, rather than
  have it inherit an altered `PATH`.
- Edit `/etc/profile` to remove the call to `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, and instead initialize `PATH` manually with something like

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
  ```

  This is not really recommended, however.

Comment: Leaving my answer here for the explanation of why the behavior differs between Linux and Mac OS X, but Charles Duffy provides a much cleaner solution than any of the three I suggested.

Comment: I like this answer, inasmuch as it's much more aware of the intricacies of OS X; has my upvote.